# Hide titles on Flickr display

Tags: flickr

Our Flickr images all have "junk" titles that were created by our camera (ie: "IMG_O123"). Is there a way to hide the title when people view your photos?

Comment: rename them to something meaningful...

Comment: I'm not interested in the titles..  and there are just too many to make the effort to rename them all meaningfully..

Answer (score 4):

No - But, there is a way to batch rename your flickr files quickly.

- Go to flickr
- Click on Organize
- In the bar at the bottom of the screen, click on Select All,
- Drag the pictures into the main screen.
- Click Edit photos and choose "Titles, tag and descriptions"
- Change the title on all photos to Blank or something meaningful.
- Click Save on each page.

It's not ideal, but it's pretty quick.

Comment: Thanks..  it's quick only depending on the number of photos..  for me it would be 67 pages worth of edits!